# Why does Vagrant require you to reinstall a plugin after running vagrant destroy?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-plugin

I'm using the [Vagrant SSHFS](https://github.com/dustymabe/vagrant-sshfs) plugin instead of `rsync`. I installed the plugin:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-sshfs
```

Below is my `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./live-build", "/home/vagrant/live-build", type: "sshfs"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "./provision/setup.sh"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "./provision/build.sh"
end
```

When I run `vagrant up` the host `live-build` directory is linked, and I can see the files from the guest.

Now if I run: `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant up` synced_folder tries to default to `rsync` which results in the following error:

```
Host path: /Users/jake/OZYProject/
Guest path: /vagrant
Command: "rsync" "--verbose" "--archive" "--delete" "-z" "--copy-links" "--no-owner" "--no-group" "--rsync-path" "sudo rsync" "-e" "ssh -p 2222 -o LogLevel=FATAL  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=/var/folders/lp/qxycffd53lxdhbhvy34lymrh0000gn/T/ssh.180 -o ControlPersist=10m  -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i '/Users/jake/OZYProject/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key'" "--exclude" ".vagrant/" "/Users/jake/OZYProject/" "vagrant@127.0.0.1:/vagrant"
Error: symlink has no referent: "/Users/jake/OZYProject/whonix-live-build/config/hooks/0010-disable-kexec-tools.hook.chroot"
...
```

What's strange is the plugin is already installed:

```
vagrant plugin list
vagrant-share (1.1.6, system)
vagrant-sshfs (1.3.0)
vagrant-vbguest (0.14.2)
```

If I attempt to install `vagrant plugin install vagrant-sshfs` (even though it's already installed) and retry `vagrant up` it will install correctly using `sshfs`. It seems I have to install `vagrant-sshfs` after running `destroy`.

Is this normal?

Comment: the issue appears for the default `/vagrant` folder. so after you install the plugin even `/vagrant` is shared with sshfs mode ?

Comment: Is there any way to disable the default folder as it's not required.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue appears for the default `/vagrant` folder, you can disable this folder by adding the following in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
```